# Where to put my hit counter code in my php class of codeigniter?

Tags: php, codeigniter, hitcounter

I've create a hit counter, and it works fine, but the problem is, I've placed that code in constructor like this:

```
// working code
<?php
class Welcome extends CI_Controller{
      function __construct()
      {
          hit_counter(); // works perfectly fine...
      }
      function view_blog()
      {
          // perfectly working code
      }
      function other_function()
      {
          // working fine
      }
}
```

Now the problem is, whenever the user visits the website for the first time, it runs the code, but when he visits `view_blog`, it also runs, when on `other_function`, it runs again, all I want to do, that my counter counts him just once, after that he should be counted only when he visits the website next time, not when he visits on various functions.

Answer (score 4):

Why not implement a PHP native session ? You could also your CI's session for this implementation.

```
<?php
session_start(); //<--- Add here
class Welcome extends CI_Controller{
    function __construct()
    {
        if(!isset($_SESSION['visited'])) 
        {
        hit_counter(); // works perfectly fine...
        $_SESSION['visited'] = true; //<--- Sets here the first time.
        }
    }
```

Comment: but how to destroy session, as soon as he goes away, since session might stay if he thinks to visit after let's say 30 seconds

Comment: he has used native session so when browser window is closed session gets destroyed.

Comment: for some odd reasons it's not working, i've closed the browser and the tab also, but doesn't seem to work on next visit :(

Comment: @avinashizhere, Session's can't be retrieved when browser is closed. So the next time when he comes, it will fire the `hitCounter()`. Can you please explain `not working` ?

Comment: let me check on live server, right now i'm using on localhost